# What does `, =` operator do?

Tags: python

What does this code do?

```
f = [1]
x, = f
```

x is set to 1 after doing this, but I cannot figure out what the `, =` does.

Comment: It's just unpacking, as if you want to define `a, b = [1, 2]`

Comment: Unpacking it is. [e.g.](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=f%20%3D%20%5B1,%202%5D%0Ax,%20y%20%3D%20f&cumulative=false&curInstr=2&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)